# How to implement database inheritance in Spring Data JPA with MapperSuperClass?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, multiple-inheritance, mappedsuperclass

I'm trying out database inheritance of type `JOINED` in Spring Data JPA, referring to [this article](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/). This worked fine. But I've to implement `MappedSuperClass` in my project. I've implemented in the following way:

> **Base.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract Long getId();
    public abstract void setId(Long id);
    public abstract String getFirstName();
    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

> **BaseImpl.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseImpl extends Base {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;

    ...
}
```

> **Super1.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Super1 extends BaseImpl {
    public abstract String getSuperName();
    public abstract void setSuperName(String guideName);
}
```

> **Super1Impl.java**

```
@Entity
public class Super1Impl extends Super1 {
    private String superName;

    ...
}
```

> **BaseBaseRepository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseBaseRepository<T extends Base> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> { }
```

> **BaseRepository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends BaseBaseRepository<Base> { }
```

> **BaseRepositoryImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
public interface BaseRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository<BaseImpl> { }
```

> **Super1Repository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface Super1Repository<T extends Super1> extends BaseBaseRepository<Super1> { }
```

> **Super1RepositoryImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
public interface Super1RepositoryImpl extends Super1Repository<Super1Impl> {  }
```

I'm trying to save a `Super1` object in a test case:

```
@Test
public void contextLoads() {
    Super1 super1 = new Super1Impl();
    super1.setSuperName("guide1");
    super1.setFirstName("Mamatha");
    super1.setEmail("jhhj");
    super1.setLastName("kkjkjhjk");
    super1.setPassword("jhjjh");
    super1.setPhoneNumber("76876876");

    System.out.println(super1Repository.save(super1));
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'baseRepositoryImpl':
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
      This class [class com.example.entity.Base] does not define an IdClass
.....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.example.entity.Base] does not define an IdClass
.......
```

Tried out `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")` in `Super1Impl`, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by incorrect repository interface declarations.

```
BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends BaseBaseRepository<Base>
```

should be

```
BaseRepository<T extends Base> extends BaseBaseRepository<T>
```

and

```
Super1Repository<T extends Super1> extends BaseBaseRepository<Super1>
```

should be

```
Super1Repository<T extends Super1> extends BaseBaseRepository<T>
```

---

As currently declared, `BaseBaseRepository<Base>` means a repository of `Base` objects and `Base` does not have an `@Id` field, hence the error.

Comment: I've retained all my code except the BaseRepository and Super1Repository. When I receive the object after saving it, I want it to be of type Super1. There is no mention of it in the Repository. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. [Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41090908) is a sample project with my corrections. You can run unit tests as `mvn clean test` to see then run fine. If you change the code to your original code, the error you have mentioned in the question will pop up immediately.

Comment: Is there any way to create generic repository, We don't need to create repository for each and every Entity ?

Comment: @VinitSolanki, yes, as long as you use EclipseLink or OpenJPA as the JPA provider. Hibernate has bugs that prevent using a generic repository. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350397/spring-data-jpa-inheritance-in-repositories/43385979#43385979) for details.